# Missing dSYM no matter what

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Firebase Crashlytics console lists this file as missing:

`D79D73EB-C9BE-3D0A-B3F5-4D6E5BF6E3A0` `1.1.1` `(1084)` `Optional`

So I successfully download symbols from
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/***/activity/ios/builds/1.1.1/1084/details

The UUID is present:

```
$ dwarfdump -u ~/Downloads/appDsyms/* | grep 3A0
UUID: D79D73EB-C9BE-3D0A-B3F5-4D6E5BF6E3A0 (arm64) /Users/gene/Downloads/appDsyms/d79d73eb-c9be-3d0a-b3f5-4d6e5bf6e3a0.dSYM
```

Then I upload it to Crashlytics, probably for the 10th time:

```
$ Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp GoogleService-Info.plist \
   -p ios ~/Downloads/appDsyms/d79d73eb-c9be-3d0a-b3f5-4d6e5bf6e3a0.dSYM

Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID d79d73ebc9be3d0ab3f54d6e5bf6e3a0 in dSYM: /Users/gene/Downloads/appDsyms/d79d73eb-c9be-3d0a-b3f5-4d6e5bf6e3a0.dSYM
```

Now I go back to Firebase Crashlitics console and still see the UUID as missing.

I did try to upload it as appDsyms.zip too, also successfully. And unzipped and upload individual files. Tried different ways of uploading maybe 10 times. All worked fine. But the UUID is still missing:

[image: fi]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Crashlytics has been partially broken for at least 4 days:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/firebase-talk/nO-NCq7p2iQ

I suppose they could not be bothered to tell us that it's been broken. The status dashboard shows "green" for the whole week.

Google, shame on you.